# Pyspark - Parse dates between multiple forward slashes

Tags: python, regex, date, parsing, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with multiple columns, one of which I want to parse out dates from as a separate column. For the following two rows, the expected output would be the following:

```
'www.freelancer/hello/there/I/am/2024/01/03/every/woijf123oijroa.fiow.com'
'www.freelancer/camping/fun/2024/02/14/foijaoijf83747199.1.com'
```

Expected date output:

```
2024/01/03
2024/02/14
```

- `df.withColumn('date', split(col('website'), '/')[5])` doesn't work because the forward slashes don't follow a set pattern and even if they did, the output results in whatever is between two brackets rather than across multiple brackets.
- Tried using `locate()` to find the index at which the dates start and to pull 10 values from that index, but it didn't function appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
20[012]\d/\d{2}/\d{2}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xIDyD5/1).

Comment: It seems to be working! .withColumn('date', regexp_extract(col('website'), r'20[012]\d/\d{2}/\d{2}', 0))\

Comment: I understand the 'd{2}/\d{2}' portions of looking for 2 digits between the slash. What does the first part of the regex mean?

Comment: @SunflowerParty: The year, ie. `2000`, `2010` or `2029`. Nothing greater than  `2029` and nothing smaller than `2000`. Just made up a small range here. You could as well use `\d{4}` instead but this could give you e.g. `0000/00/00` which is not a date.